# WPF Binding to ComboBox in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I am trying to make a UserControl with a ComboBox and binding to the ItemSource and SelectedItem (I also have some other controls with binding in the UserControl, but those are working fine and have been removed to simplify the code below).

The ItemSource binding seems to be working and the ComboBox is populated with the list specified in the MainWindow, but the SelectedItem is not updated on a change in either direction. Although the VersionText  is updated on a change of the SelectedSoftwareVersion.Version outside of the UserControl.

I am probaly missing something basic here, but I cannot see it. I have limited experience wiht UserControls.

SoftwareTile.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.SoftwareTile"
             x:Name="softwareTile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="150">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">

        <StackPanel>

            <TextBlock x:Name="VersionText"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=softwareTile, Path=Version}"/>


            <TextBlock x:Name="VersionLabel"
                       Text="Version"/>

            <ComboBox x:Name="VersionSelect"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=softwareTile, Path=VersionList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=softwareTile, Path=VersionSelected}"/>

        </StackPanel>
            
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

SoftwareTile.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;
        
namespace MyApp.Controls
{

    public partial class SoftwareTile : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Version", typeof(string), typeof(SoftwareTile), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VersionList", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SoftwareTile), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VersionSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VersionSelected", typeof(object), typeof(SoftwareTile), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public string Version
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(VersionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VersionProperty, value); }
        }

        public IEnumerable VersionList
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(VersionListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VersionListProperty, value); }
        }

        public object VersionSelected
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(VersionSelectedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VersionSelectedProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<uc:SoftwareTile x:Name="ST1"
                 Version="{Binding SelectedSoftwareVersion.Version}" 
                 VersionList="{Binding SoftwareVersions.VersionList}" 
                 VersionSelected="{Binding SelectedSoftwareVersion.Version, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Are you sure your UserControl should have two different properties, Version and VersionSelected, that both bind to the same view model property? Seems redundant. Also note that setting the top level Grid's DataContext in the UserControl's XAML seems redundant. All Bindings there have an explictly set source object (by `ElementName=softwareTile`).

Comment: Besides that, make sure the `SelectedSoftwareVersion.Version` property in your view model fires a change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: As a note, the VersionSelected property should be registered with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`.

Comment: Try adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the binding

Comment: @Clemens, is it essential in this case?
The binding explicitly states TwoWay.

Comment: @Clemens I have tried with and without the two different properties that binds to SelectedSoftwareVersion.Version. The "Version" property was just for testing, to see that I can read the value in into the UserControl. INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented and fires change notification when changed in the ViewModel, however not when changing from the UserControl ComboBox. Where/how do I add FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault?

Comment: @RyanThomas  Adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged had no effect.

Comment: @Clemens I figured out the FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, but it does not seem to help with the issue.

Comment: @norsemanGrey: What is `SelectedSoftwareVersion`? You forgot to post the view model.